Linear map from smooth vector field to smooth functions on a manifold is determined pointwise
I'm trying to prove this theorem: If $M$ is a smooth manifold and $F\in Lin_{C_{\infty}(M)}(\mathfrak{X}(M), C_{\infty}(M))$, then $F$ is determined pointwise.
Proof attempt: Let $X$ be a smooth vector field and $p\in M$ such that $X(p)=0$. We then need to show that $F(X)(p)=0$. Let $(U,x)$ be a chart around $p$, in which the representation of $X$ is $X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$. Since $X(p)=X^i(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\big|_p=0$, we have $X^i(p)=0$ for all $i$.
$$F(X)(p)=F(X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})(p)=\big(X^iF(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})\big)(p)=X^i(p)F(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})(p)=0$$
Is this proof fine? I'm not sure because coordinate-dependent proofs can present some sneaky problems that I'm not able to always see. If there's a flaw in the above proof, any way to make it more airtight?

did you look at standard textbooks and compare your proofs?

@peek-a-boo: Yes I compared to one book (Semi-Riemannian geometry by Newman) - but the proof there states "Only the case where $M$ is covered by a single chart $(M,x)$ is considered". And his logic there is the same as mine, but it seems like a single chart for $M$ is a very specific case. I'm not sure if that's enough to prove the theorem in general.

@peek-a-boo: Also I understand the John Lee's books are the most standard, but I don't have access to those at the moment

Almost, but not quite. Notice that writing $F(X^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i})$ does not make sense, beacuse $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a local object, not a global vector field in $M$. You need to prove first that $F$ is determined by its value in neighborhoods. You can easily prove this using partitions of unity.

@RUBÉNIZQUIERDOLÓPEZ: Thank you for the hint. I'll work on it some more and update the proof in the question in a while
